# Golang Determining whether *File points to file or directory

Tags: file, go

Is there a way to determine whether my *File is pointing to a file or a directory?

```
fileOrDir, err := os.Open(name)
// How do I know whether I have a file or directory?
```

I want to be able to read stats about the file if it is just a file, and be able to read the files within the directory if it is a directory

```
fileOrDir.Readdirnames(0) // If dir
os.Stat(name) // If file
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    name := "FileOrDir"
    fi, err := os.Stat(name)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    switch mode := fi.Mode(); {
    case mode.IsDir():
        // do directory stuff
        fmt.Println("directory")
    case mode.IsRegular():
        // do file stuff
        fmt.Println("file")
    }
}
```

Note:

The example is for Go 1.1. For Go 1.0, replace `case mode.IsRegular():` with `case mode&os.ModeType == 0:`.

Answer (score 40):

Here is another possibility:

```
import "os"

func IsDirectory(path string) (bool, error) {
    fileInfo, err := os.Stat(path)
    if err != nil{
      return false, err
    }
    return fileInfo.IsDir(), err
}
```

Comment: be careful: directory has to exist

Comment: This segfaults if the given path does not exist.

Add `if err != nil { return false, nil}` before the return to make it safer.

Answer (score 17):

Here is how to do the test in one line:

```
    if info, err := os.Stat(path); err == nil && info.IsDir() {
       ...
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
fileOrDir, err := os.Open(name)
if err != nil {
  ....
}
info, err := fileOrDir.Stat()
if err != nil {
  ....
}
if info.IsDir() {
   .... 
} else {
   ...
}
```

Be careful to not open and stat the file by name. This will produce a race condition with potential security implications.

If your open succeeds then your have a valid file handle and you should use the Stat() method on it to obtain the stat. The top answer is risky because they suggest to call os.Stat() first and then presumably os.Open() but someone could change the file in between the two calls.

Comment: Nope: `multiple-value fileOrDir.Stat() in single-value context`

Comment: use: `info,err:=fileOrDir.Stat()` `if info.IsDir() {...}`

Answer (score 1):

```
import "os"

// FileExists reports whether the named file exists as a boolean
func FileExists(name string) bool {
    if fi, err := os.Stat(name); err == nil {
        if fi.Mode().IsRegular() {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

// DirExists reports whether the dir exists as a boolean
func DirExists(name string) bool {
    if fi, err := os.Stat(name); err == nil {
        if fi.Mode().IsDir() {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```